# Display an image in picture box using next and previous button

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I am now displaying an image from picturebox but my problem is to display an image using next button and previous button.

This is my load code:

```
    Private Sub me_load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    disconnect()
    connect()
    cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand("Select stud_pic from tablestudent order by section desc", con)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If dr.HasRows Then
        dr.Read()
        Dim data As Byte() = DirectCast(dr("stud_pic"), Byte())
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream(data)
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
        PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    End If
End Sub
```

Next And Previous button:

```
  Private Sub btnnext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnnext.Click
 'Do here
 End Sub
```

Comment: You have several problems.  All the data objects are local to the Form Load event so there is nothing your buttons can do.  Second a DataReader is forward only, so there is no way to go backwards.  Load the entire result data to a form level DataSet/DataTable  then just navigate it via the buttons, or add a Navigator.

Comment: It may be easier to use a slideshow extender

Comment: If possible, store a file path instead of the image it self. A database storage is generally more expensive than file storage.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestion, I got my solution, but im still having a problem how can I display their first and last name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub me_load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    disconnect()
    connect()
    DA = New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter("Select stud_pic from tablestudent order by section desc", con)
    DA.Fill(DS)

    counter = 0

    Me.PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
End Sub

Private Function GetImageFromByteArray(ByVal picData As Byte()) As Image
    If picData Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Dim bmData As Integer = IIf((picData(0) = 21 AndAlso picData(1) = 28), 78, 0)

    ' load the picture 
    Dim img As Image = Nothing
    Try
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream(picData, bmData, picData.Length - bmData)
        img = Image.FromStream(ms)
    Catch
    End Try ' return what we got Return img
    Return img

End Function

Private Sub btnnext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnnext.Click
    PictureBox1.Image = GetImageFromByteArray(DS.Tables(0).Rows.Item(counter).Item(0))
    If counter < Me.DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 Then
        counter += 1
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnprev_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnprev.Click
    PictureBox1.Image = GetImageFromByteArray(DS.Tables(0).Rows.Item(counter).Item(0))
    If counter > 0 Then
        counter -= 1
    End If
End Sub
```